# copy form to Backbone.js model

Tags: javascript, model, backbone.js

I have a form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email" >
    <input type="text" name="phone" >
    <input type="button" value="ok" />
</form>
```

When clicking the button, I'd like to copy the form values to a corresponding model.

I've found [Backbone.ModelBinder](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder) which will automatically copy values to model whenever the values are changed, but that's not what I want, I just want to copy the values when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a custom function into the view where the form is located and bind it to the ok click event:

```
events: {
  ...
  'click input[name="ok"]': 'copyFormToModel'
  ...
},

...

copyFormToModel: function() {
  var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
  var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();

  // Perform some sort of validation

  this.model.email = email;
  this.model.phone = phone;
}
```

This isn't the prettiest answer, but if you have just one small form in your page, then using some library or plugin might be a bit overkill. If you want to use a plugin or library, then for your case I think [backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms) could do the trick. It features updating the model bound to the form with a method call rather than every time fields are updated.

Answer (score 0):

This code may be you need：

```
events: {
  ...
  'click input[value="ok"]': 'collectData2Model'
  ...
},

...
//suppose employee is your model
collectData2Model: function(e) {
    var employee = new Employee();
    var attr = {};
     $('input').each(function(){
            var input = $(this);
            attr[input.attr('name')] = input.val();
      });
       employee.bind('error',function(model,error){
            alert(error);
        });
      // set method will automatically call the model's validate method 
       employee.set(attr);
}
```